# FirebaseFirestore.get returning null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data from Firestore.

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
bool abcd;
final adsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('All ads');
getData(){
adsRef.get().then((snap) {
  snap.docs.forEach((doc) { 
    abcd=doc.data().isEmpty;
  });
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: Text("TestPage"),
  ),
  body: FlatButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print(abcd);
    },
    child: Text("data"),
  ),
  );
  }
  }
```

Here's the DB:
[image: DB]

And I've tried getting `doc.id`, `doc.exists`, etc
 but
It's returning 'null'.

PS: I'm a newbie to firebase.

Comment: Where are you calling `getData()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase/Firestore (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously, and needs to be passed to the UI through a `setState()` call (or another state management primitive).

You should:

1. start loading the data in the `initState` method of the class
2. then call `setState()` when the data is available (or changes)
3. this will trigger the `build()` method, where you can then use the data from the state

So something like:

```
class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  bool abcd;
  final adsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('All ads');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    adsRef.get().then((snap) {
      snap.docs.forEach((doc) { 
        setState(() {
          abcd=doc.data().isEmpty;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("TestPage"),
      ),
      body: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(abcd);
        },
        child: Text("data"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Async/Await" to get data from firebase

async getData()

and call

data = await getData() like this.